# Running visual studio 2015 on parallels c1033 error

Tags: macos, visual-studio-2015, parallels

Running visual studio 2015 on parallels and overtime I create a project and go to build it I get error code `c1033`

> Error C1033   cannot open program database '\Mac\Home\Documents\visual
>   Studio\FinAccSim\FinAccSim\Debug\vc140.idb'

Ive tried rebuilding it afterwards and its still the same, also deleted the .db file but same error still occurs. i am utterly clueless as to what the problem is

Answer (score 1):

There are several answers to this problem on SO. Your problem is caused by having the project on a shared folder. VS likely having problems accessing the file.

Move the project into a folder completely inside the Parallels world.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem.

1 of 3) Shut down Windows virtual machine, open its configuration.

2 of 3) Go to Hardware tab > Boot Order > and paste in Boot Flags box:

**tools.prl_fs.fileids.enable=1**

3 of 3) Run Windows and check the issue.

Ciao, agx.

At the following URL, it explains how to fix it.

https://forum.parallels.com/threads/shared-folder-issue-after-update-to-11-1-0.330539/